# Exclude logged-in users traffic using the User Id custom dimension

Tags: google-analytics

I need to analyze the traffic of my logged and unlogged users separately.
So I have implemented the user id functionality and I have configured a view for **logged in users** and everything OK, now I need to create a view only for **unlogged users**.

I have created the new view and I am trying to add a filter to exclude the traffic by specifying the custom dimension of User Id in the Filter Field, but I don't know what to put in the Filter Pattern since in this case the User Id dimension has a status Unassigned and has no detectable value by any regular expression I know of.

Any help please!

Answer (score 0):

Try to check if it undefined or its length is less than the length of an your normal userid.